# ListView leaderboard is too spaced out, can I make the rows closer?

Tags: java, android, xml

Right now I have a ListView that shows high scores in a database. My rows right now are very spaced out, and I'd like them to be closer. However I can't figure this out. Here's what my tables look like on the emulator:

[image]

Here's my code:
Here is Leaderboard xml:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/display_listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time" />
```

Here is Leaderboard_row xml:

```
<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mathAnswer"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-----------"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/lb_rank"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-----------"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/lb_score"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lb_rank"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-----------"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/lb_time"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lb_score"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there something I can do to make these rows closer together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xml looks pretty messed up. you are using a lot of attributes that are only for relative layout. Try this:

```
<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-----------"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/lb_rank"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-----------"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/lb_score"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-----------"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/lb_time"
        android:gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any reason you took out layout weight?

Comment: @Milap layout weight doesnt do anything if your layout width or height isnt 0

Comment: I just realized my relativelayout that my linearlayout is in has a height of 75dp......Can't believe I missed that, that solves my problem. Thanks for the other tips though!

Answer (score 0):

The line - *android:layout_marginTop="10dp"* in Leaderboard_row Linear Layout is adding space between rows. Removing this line should place the rows one below the other with out any space between them.

And android:layout_alignParentLeft, android:layout_toRightOf are Relative Layout properties and should not be used inside Linear Layout.

Comment: i think most of the space is coming from below the layout not on top. thats what it looks like from the divider anyway

Comment: Forgot about the margin. I took that away and there's still a substantial gap. Thanks for the top about Relative properties though.